# Very bad server response time. how to fixed?

Tags: linux

There are many images on a heavy template of word press installed on web site here @
puttinout.com

usually my server went down and we facing bad experience from our readers. Please guide me the possible best solution according to my site need.

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners here.

Comment: Hire a programmer. At least use Internet Explorer network profiling (behnd F12) to see all the hugh amounts of partially ridiculous slow requests are you pulling. I mean, seriously - I get 261 requests here on that homepage.

Comment: Hire a consultant with expertise in website optimization.  Seriously, this is not a "do my job for me" or a "free professional services" website.

Comment: Shobee : The problems with your site are extensive. Nobody will be able to help you without a deeper understanding of your site, which is something that can't really be done via a Q&A site such as ServerFault or any Forum sites on the Internet. You will need to learn how to do it yourself (which will take time) or hire a consultant.

Answer (score 3):

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dmcRzA/http://www.puttinout.com/ indicates 230 HTTP requests and 4.3 megabytes of data to load that site.

This has little to do with your server (although large numbers of HTTP requests can slow things down server-side as well as client-side) and more to do with the coding of the site.

Comment: Whow. SERIOUSLY? 230 HTTP Requests is INSANE. Whow.

Comment: @ceejayoz Will you please explain 230 HTTP requests and 4.3 megabytes of data to load that site?

Comment: @Shobee You coded it, you explain it! The link I gave shows you all the requests and the file sizes of each.

Comment: @ceejayoz so is that bad or Good? Actually i am very confused ? or if very bad then what to do? Please

Comment: It's very bad. Even on a fast connection it's going to take quite a while to load. Google "website optimization" and start learning - it's a big topic.